# Using replace to select part of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Hello I'm new to javascript and I need a little help with regex/replace

I want to take a url for example (url case 1)

> http://url.com/_t_lastUpdate_2670619?location=50457347

or (url case 2)

> http://url.com/_t_2670619

I want to select in this case just

```
_t_2680619
```

Ignore everything after "?" and before (underscore)t(underscore)

Is it possible with regex/replace? the only thing I managed to do was select numbers only with

```
var _t__and_number = document.URL.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
alert(_t__and_number);
```

But that doesn't solve my problem if there's something like url case 1

(if I could get just the first number even without the (underscore)t(underscore) it would already help me a lot.
Thanks

## Solutions:

[onetrickpony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198899/using-replace-to-select-part-of-a-url#comment26671396_18198899)/michaelb958:

```
var _t__and_number = window.location.pathname;
alert(_t__and_number);
```

ermagana:

```
var _t__and_number = document.URL.replace(/\?.*/g, '').match(/.*\/(.*)/)[1];
alert(_t__and_number);
```

Comment: That's the path, right? `window.location.pathname` should give you that

Comment: Oh my god.... is it that simple?

Comment: what if you have `http://url.com/something_else/_t_...`?

Comment: I don't think that will happen in my case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [onetrickpony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198899/using-replace-to-select-part-of-a-url#comment26671396_18198899), if this is the URL you are currently browsing, `window.location.pathname` will yield that part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

First Part like case (1) and (2)

```
    var s = '//url.com/_t_522121?location=50457347';
    var n = s.lastIndexOf('/');
    var result = s.substring(n + 1);
    alert(result);

    n = result.indexOf('?');
    result = result.substring(0, n);
    alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pull out the value after the last / and before the ? you could try something like this

```
url.replace(/\?.*/g, '').match(/.*\/.*(_t_.*)/)[1]
```

The replace removes everything from the ? and forward, the match creates a group of the values found after the last forward slash which is then accessed by the index [1](http://jsfiddle.net/ermagana/DedXZ/)

Hope this helps.

here is the jsfiddle to show it works:
[My JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermagana/DedXZ/)

Comment: This doesn't remove the text if the URL is for example http://url.com/asdasda_asdasd_t_2670619 but I can deal with that, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you're referring to, see my updated answer @GabeNewell

Comment: That did not work...
var test = document.URL.replace(/\?.*/g, '').match(/.*\/(_t_.*)/)[1];
alert(test);

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: what browser are you running? I'm assuming you want the text starting from the underscore before the t and after until it hits a question mark, is that right?

Comment: Chrome. Yes and no, it's not everytime it will have a question mark, mostly it will be just _t_number or text_t_number

Comment: so please answer the following: 1. in url.com/asdasda_asdasd_t_123456 what are you expecting to get back? 2. in url.com/asd_asd_t_1234?otherstuff what are you expecting to get back? these two answers should help me understanding your goal

Comment: 1. _t_123456, 2. _t_1234

Comment: ok, if that's the case then my answer should give you what you need.